# what is the postgreSQL 9.2 counterpart to this SQL Server if exists ({sql-statement}) conditional construct

Tags: sql, plpgsql, conditional-statements, postgresql-9.2

I have this in a stored proc in SQL Server:

```
      if not exists
        (my select statement)
            insert T
               (a, b, c)
            values
               (v_a, v_b, v_c)      -- arguments passed to the function


      select a,b,c from T where...;    -- return the row to the client after inserting it
```

Does postgreSQL have a counterpart to that `if exists ( {select-statement} )` construct?  The plpgsql compiler at first told me there was a missing "THEN" but when I corrected the `if ... then` syntax:

```
     create function foo(v_a int, v_b int, v_c int)
     returns TABLE (a int, b int, c int)
     as $body$
     begin
        if not exists
          (select id from T where ...) then
           insert into T
             (a, b, c)
           values
             (v_a, v_b, v_c);

       return QUERY
       select a,b,c from T where ...   ;

     end
     $body$
     LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

the compilation terminates with:

```
       ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
       LINE 52: $body$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
       .........^
```

so I'm assuming there's some error upstream, but I don't see it.

Comment: Most of the `if exists` functionality can be put in the `where` clause (where it belongs), also avoiding potential doubling of the query-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IF` clause is incomplete. It must be closed by the corresponding `END IF` statement.

Check the docs [on conditionals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS).